# Creating instance in Application class

Tags: android, singleton, android-application-class

I am developing an Android Application, in which I am using Network libraries Retroift with GSON,Otto and Realm. So am creating instance in application class( extends Application). It makes my app launching time very slow. Is there any alternate solution to solve this out.

```
 public class MyApp extends Application{

     private MyApp appInstance;
     private MainThreadBus bus;
     private RealmConfiguration myAppRealmConfig;
     private GSON gson;
     private HttpLoggingInterceptor logging;


     @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            //Application instance
            appInstance = this;
            gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat(ApiConstants.API_DATE_FORMAT).setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                    .serializeNulls()
                    .create();
            mAppRealmConfig =   RealmConfigurationFactory.createMyAppRealmConfiguration(this, secretKey);
            appConfig = new AppConfig();  logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        bus = new MainThreadBus();

    }

   public Gson getGson() {
        return gson;
    }

    public AppConfig getAppConfig() {
        return appConfig;
    }

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't tell. Well I believe it is because of too much load on the activity thread .

Comment: Like above, can you please.. @utkarshdubey

Comment: Well I am not sure this method will work or not but If you want you can try ASYNC TASK concept in your code .Search it on Google !